# PyQt6: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, import, pyqt, pyqt6

`Windows 10` `PyCharm` `Python 3.9.0`

I installed `PyQt6` and then `pyqt6-tools` in `PyCharm` throw the *File->Settings*.

Now when i run my program i am getting the following error in the terminal

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
PyQt6: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

My program code

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication(sys.args)

window = QWidget()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: run it in a virtual enviornment

Answer (score 2):

The following command helped me solve this problem:

```
pip install --upgrade PyQt6
```